# How to edit NAMESPACE with roxygen2 when creating R packages?

Tags: r, r-package

I am writing an R package and in the following link,

[How can I load dependencies in an R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46289327/how-can-i-load-dependencies-in-an-r-package)
a response indicates that it is necessary to "add a line in your NAMESPACE file importFrom(ncdf4, nc_open) and then in your code, call the function without the package: nc_open(...)"

and here,
[How to properly include dependencies in R-package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565024/how-to-properly-include-dependencies-in-r-package)
an user says:

"The NAMESPACE file. Here you declare the packages you need

import(ggplot2)
or to avoid namespace clashes

importFrom(ggplot2, geom_point)
You can get roxygen2 to maintain the NAMESPACE file using the @import and @importFrom tags."

These recommendations look straightforward. However, as I create NAMESPACE with the r package roxygen2, the file NAMESPACE cannot be edited manually.

Then, how to edit the file NAMESPACE?

Very much thank you in advance

Comment: Here is a great resource for package development: https://r-pkgs.org/

Answer (score 4):

If you need full example, this is how it could look:

```
#' Title
#'
#' @return
#' @export
#' @import ggplot2
#' @importFrom data.table setDT
#' @examples
my_function <- function() {
  
}
```

To insert roxygen2 skeleton - go to "Code" tab in RStudio and search Insert Roxygen Skeleton.

tag `@export` indicates that `my_function` will be exported to be visible for users, when using `package::my_fun` or after `library(package)`. Tag `@import` makes all exported functions from `ggplot2` package available for you, i.e. no need to use `ggplot2::aes()` when you use functions from this package in your package. Tag `@importFrom` makes available only explicitly mentioned function from package, i.e. no need to use `package::fun()`, but it will be necessary for other functions from this package.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to use

```r
#' @export
```

or

```r
#' @importFrom
```

preferably in the files (and above) the code that make use of these imports. See [Vignette on Roxygen2, NAMESPACE tags](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html)
Then a call to `devtools::document()` will generate the appropriate `NAMESPACE`, etc. through these annotations.